# Filling Google Form through Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a database of `name, phone number, address`.

And I have 3 questions in the form:

1. name
2. phone number
3. address

If someone filled his name, I want the form to *auto-answer* his phone number and address. OR view his phone number and address somewhere on the form.

Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms hasn't a feature that helps to make this possible.

One alternative is to create a web app by using Google Apps Script.